# "Please Wait" popup message

Tags: vba, excel, popup

I am trying to create a `Please Wait` message in Excel VBA. This is to remind the user processing a SQL query that the process is still ongoing. I would like to have this message displayed in a userform.

Currently, the user connects to SQL DB, selects database and some other options, presses Go... and the form does not unload. At the Go point I have another form which pops up with message `Please Wait`, but this form does not unload, i.e. the SQL execute command does not run.

My code for calling the `Please Wait` userform, including a label:

```
   Call WaitShowSQl.ExecuteCall KillWaitCall WaitShow
   SQl.Execute
   Call KillWait
```

In another code module I have:

```
   Sub WaitShow()
   Wait.Show
   End Sub

   Sub KillWait()
   Unload Wait
   End Sub
```

I have userform called `wait` with following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Call PleaseWait
End Sub 

Sub PleaseWait()
Wait.Label1.Caption = "Calculating...Please Wait!"
End Sub
```

Now when executing the code, the run-time does not move back through the module in order to execute the following:

```
SQl.ExecuteSQl.Execute
```

I can show the progress of the program with a status bar, but a userform popup message would be very useful for this program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behavior of the Form.Show method is to show the form as a modal dialog.  What you are looking for is a modeless dialog box, so you need to specify that, like this:

```
Sub WaitShow()
   Wait.Show vbModeLess
End Sub
```

Update:

If you can't user a modeless dialog, you have other options, as mentioned in a comment.  One of them is to let the wait userform do the SQL executing.  This could be done like this:

In the wait form, first declare variables

```
Private mySomeParameter1 As String
Private mySomeReturnValue1 As String

'Input parameters to the form
Public Sub Init(ByVal some_parameter1 As String, ...)
... Initialize your SQL, NOT execute it
End Sub

'Output values from the from
Public Sub GetReturns(ByRef some_return_value1 As String, ...)
... set the output parameters...
End Sub

'Do the work
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Call PleaseWait
  'Either call DoEvents or a manual Refresh to let the label display itself
  Call ExecutSQL    ' A function that executes the SQL
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

And in the main form:

```
Sub WaitShow()
   Wait.Init(the parameters...)
   Wait.Show
   Wait.GetReturns(the results...)
End Sub
```

Yet another option for you would be to skip the Wait form completely and instead show an "Waiting" Image on the mainform and hide it when the SQL processing is done.

Comment: THanks for reply GTG. I have already tried that and get this: Can't show non-modal form when modal form is displayed.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the first form where the user select the options is still displayed.

Comment: Assuming your first form need to be modal, then you can either put your SQL Execution code inside the "Waiting" userform or call a function in the parent form from the "Waiting" userform.  That way you don't need any extra modules.  A third option would be to create an ActiveX .exe for the "Waiting" form and let that process show a modeless "Waiting" form.  That however would require that you deploy that .exe along with your Excel sheet.

Comment: But if i put the SQL Execution inside the "Waiting" userform, how will it go back to the main module where the waiting form was called from? as i need to execute other stuff from the main module after SQL Exec.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to show a progress bar while your users are waiting for Excel to finish processing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791349/138938

[image: Excel progress bar]

In your case, you can guess a reasonable "average" time for your queries and have the progress bar update with percentages of that time, which will reassure your users that Excel is working and they don't need to panic.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is far less elegant and impressive than the others.  FYI, my script is doing processing for a number of partners within a FOR...NEXT loop, and I want to update the screen with the partner currently being processed.

I created a worksheet tab called "Messages".  I expanded cell A1 as wide and tall as I could, and I picked a font that I liked a color scheme that I liked.  My script starts by turning off ScreenUpdating.  I then

```
Sheets("Messages").Select
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Processing " & Partner
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

After this, I return to whatever sheet I need.  Nothing fancy, but it's fast, easy, and does what I need. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a command button on the form set to a very small size, hidden when the form loads, with the caption "Please wait, processing..."

I resize the button in the form Iniliatlise event (I simply resize to the form size using the top, left, width & height properties). YOu can of course make it whatever size you like.

I make the command button visible just before my time consuming code & make it hidden again at the end of the code.

Requires some "DoEvents", but works perfectly.